# How to embedded apple script in a link in HTML?

Tags: applescript, html

I tried to embedded apple script in a link in HTML, but all it does is brought up the Apple Script Editor Application with profiled script in it.

I want it to **execute** after I click on the link - so I don't have to press the **play** button.

Can someone help me fix this real quick ?

`link.html`

```
<a href = " 

applescript://com.apple.scripteditor?
action=new&script=

tell application %22Safari%22%0D%09
make new document with properties {URL:%22https://www.google.com%22}%0D%09 

end tell "> 

Click me to run the script ! 

</a>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is done for security reasons as anything in your browser can just open a URL, which means it could run arbitrary code.

Comment: Are you saying that what I am trying to do is impossible ? correct ?

Comment: No actually it is possible, just a bad idea :) You'd have to make your own url scheme to run it.

Comment: I am totally with you. I am 100% aware of that, but for the sake of getting this working, do you know how to make this work ? :D

Comment: There was definitely an app that let you do this, but I can't find it...

Comment: Please let me know if you do.

Answer (score 1):

The app is called **[LinCastor](https://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/)**. (It can also be installed with homebrew cask if you have it.)

First click "add new scheme" in the bottom left of the main window, then change the title to whatever you like and the "scheme(s)" to `x-applescript-runner`.

Change the "handler" below from AppleScript to Shell, and paste this code in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

THE_PASSWORD = 'secret'

import os
import urlparse
import subprocess

params = urlparse.parse_qs(os.environ["URL_QUERY"].lstrip('?'))

password = params['password'][0]
script = params['script'][0]

if password == THE_PASSWORD:
    subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', script])
```

Hit "Save and Activate", then test it with this url:

```
x-applescript-runner://?password=secret&script=display%20dialog%20%22hello%22%0A
```

Obviously you'll want to change the password from `secret` to something better like `V2VkIEZlYiAxMSAyMjo0MjozOSBFU1QgMjAxNQo=` (but not that either!). The password should make it slightly more secure, but of course anyone who sees your URL will still be able to run whatever they want with a URL.